# Loading a link within the same page jQuery

Tags: jquery, load, window

This code is for a filterable portfolio. Originally I had PHP for the next and previous links, but when the portfolio is filtered it doesn't find the next filtered object. I found that the filter places the list items next to each other in the DOM so I used next() to get the result. However, the link isnt loading properly. Its a link on the same page that loads thickbox. I have successfully got it to open in a new window and append to the window url, but no dice trying to get it to work. Here is the address of said portfolio.

http://blurosemedia.com/portfolio

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".portfolio-next").click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.data('clicked', true)) {
    var namer = $(this).attr('value');
    var url = $(this).parents('body').children('#wrap').children('#inner').children('#content-sidebar-wrap').children('#content').children('ul#portfolio-list').children().next('.portfolio-item-' + namer).nextAll('.portfolio-item:not(:.isotope-hidden)').attr('id');
        window.location.load(url);
        e.preventDefault();
   }
        });
});
```

I had to climb all the way up the dow tree because the thickbox code automatically shows on the bottom of the page. One possible solution I thought was in order to get thickbox to load you must have class="thickbox". If I could somehow say load(url).withClass('thickbox') it might work, but I'm sure how the syntax should be.

Answer (score 0):

you have many things to sort out, but here's some information to help you going to the right path:

## 1)

**window.location.load** does not exits, what you are looking for is `window.location.href`:

See the documentation [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

See the documentation [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms952653.aspx)

**e.g.,** `window.location.href = url;`

---

## 2)

**Additionally,**

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

You are setting the li's with an ID that starts with `#`.

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/352449) for additional information!

**Workaround for this:**

```
<li id="#TB_inline?height=450&width=900&inlineId=id-3" class="portfolio-item design portfolio-item-3 isotope-item">...</li>
```

**Can be:**

```
<li class="portfolio-item design portfolio-item-3 isotope-item">
 <span style="display:none;">#TB_inline?height=450&width=900&inlineId=id-3</span>
</li>
```

---

## 3)

You are traveling the DOM up and down for no reason. Since you have an ID present at the wrapper for your items (`#portfolio-list`), you can target it and start from there!

**Also,**

```
('.portfolio-item:not(:.isotope-hidden)')
```

**Should be:**

```
('.portfolio-item:not(.isotope-hidden)')
```

**Using** `:not(:something)`, is used to target an element with a certain state, like `:checked`

See [this Link](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) for further information!

---

## 4)

Since the variable `namer` gets the current id of the opened item, and you want to pass to the next one, **You code becomes:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".portfolio-next").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);

    var namer = parseInt($this.attr('value'))+1;
    var url   = $this.attr("href");
        url   = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('=id'));
     
   window.location.href(url+"=id"+namer);
  });
});
```

See this [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/dBwbf/)!

Take note that the tag `a` does not have any attribute `value`, so it is invalid markup.

See [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for you detailed response. This is my first time really diving into jQuery. This is What I came up with:

```
<?php echo '<a href="#TB_inline?height=450&amp;width=900&amp;inlineId=id-" class="thickbox     
portfolio-previous" value="'; echo $portnum; echo '">Previous</a>';echo '<a 
href="#TB_inline?height=450&amp;width=900&amp;inlineId=id-" class="thickbox portfolio-
next" value="'; echo $portnum; echo '">Next</a>';?>

    //Next Portfolio Button
$(".portfolio-next").hover(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var $this = $(this);
//Get the value of the link which is the same value as the current list item
var namer = parseInt($this.attr('value'));
//Find the current div in the dom and find the list item id next to it
var falcon = $('ul#portfolio-list').children('.portfolio-item-' +    
namer).nextAll('.portfolio-item:not(:.isotope-hidden)').attr('id');

//Find the href tag  id and add the value from falcon
var url   = $this.attr("href");
url   = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('=id'));
if(falcon === undefined) {
var falcon2 = $('ul#portfolio-list').children('.portfolio-item-' +   
namer).prevAll('.portfolio-item:not(:.isotope-hidden):first').attr('id');
$(this).attr('href', url+"=id-"+falcon2);
}else{
$(this).attr('href', url+"=id-"+falcon);
return;
}
});

//Previous Portfolio Button

$(".portfolio-previous").hover(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var $this = $(this);
//Get the value of the link which is the same value as the current list item
var namer = parseInt($this.attr('value'));
//Find the current div in the dom and find the list item id next to it
var falcon = $('ul#portfolio-list').children('.portfolio-item-' +     
namer).prevAll('.portfolio-item:not(:.isotope-hidden)').attr('id');

//Find the href tag  id and add the value from falcon
var url   = $this.attr("href");
  url   = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('=id'));
  if(falcon === undefined) {
  var falcon2 = $('ul#portfolio-list').children('.portfolio-item-' +   
namer).nextAll('.portfolio-item:not(:.isotope-hidden):last').attr('id');
  $(this).attr('href', url+"=id-"+falcon2);
}else{
$(this).attr('href', url+"=id-"+falcon);
return;
}
});
```

It work but any suggestions on how to optimize would be greatly appreciated.